# How to display Views fields as a drop down menu?

Tags: views, navigation

I have several fields in a View which I would like to appear as a drop down when another field is hovered over. It is possible to create a jump menu and a [fieldset](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_fieldset) in Views, but how does one create a drop down menu? I have tried using the [Block Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/blockreference) module but this doesn't seem to show in Views. The only other option I can think of is writing the HTML in a global Views field and using replacement patterns, but there's got to be a better way. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the specific context - are you simply wanting to use the view results as a menu (in which case [Menu Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_views) would do this), or are you wanting to display a number of items e.g. users, and have more detailed info on the items spill out on hover (in which case, a display format such as [Views App Folders](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_app_folders) might be what you're looking for).

Comment: Menu Views or Menu MiniPanels would work if an entire menu item could be added as a field in a View, which I think it can't be. The second example you gave is closer to what I'm looking for. Consider a field displayed in a View such as Node Title, when hovering over this field it drops down a list (also controlled by Views) of all of the comments made on that node. Therefore it functions exactly like a drop down menu however through Views the drop down contents can be controlled and the menu position can be controlled also. I haven't tried Views App Folders yet, I will test this out. Thank you

Comment: Ok I tried Views App Folders out and it is in the right direction, but it works more like a fieldset than a drop down menu. It also does not work on hover but only on click, I am looking for more of a tooltip like functionality. I have tried using Views Tooltip module however the problem with this is that you can only define 1 style for all of the tooltips for the entire site, which is not very flexible. Any other suggestions on how to achieve this functionality?